# A homemade breakfast

Tags: word-choice

Do the  first and second   sentences sound less natural?

1."We carry/have  a cold home-made breakfast to school."

2."We have/carry a cold breakfast made at home by our parents."

3. "We carry homemade breakfast to school."

The first two sentences are mine. The third sentence expresses what I mean but it's short and from the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence works only with *carry*:

> *We **have**... a breakfast **to school** .

doesn't work at all.

For the second sentence, either *have* or *carry* works. Which you use depends on what you want to emphasize - bringing it to school, or having or eating it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different questions at work here: 1) can you have "a breakfast"? (yes) 2) How do you use "have" vs "carry" and 3) how do we fit "home" and "school" into the sentence? Let's take them in order:

1. *We carry a cold home-made breakfast to school* — This is grammatically valid and idiomatically natural. You could also use another verb like "bring," which might be still more natural.
2. *We have a cold home-made breakfast to school* — The only problem here is that "have" doesn't pair with "to" (at least, not in this way). You could say "we have breakfast *at* school," but "have breakfast" is an idiom meaning "eat breakfast," and your example seems to be more interested in talking about how you bring the food than when you eat it.
3. *We carry a cold breakfast made at home by our parents* — This is also grammatically valid. It doesn't mention school, but maybe that's okay if it's clear from the context. For some reason, while "bring" seems like a slightly more natural verb than "carry," in the first example, it seems *much* more natural here.  "Carry" often focuses very directly and immediately on how you're transporting something, even thinking about how you're holding it, while "bring" simply conveys that you brought it along.
4. *We have a cold breakfast made at home by our parents* — Since "have breakfast" idiomatically means "eat breakfast," and since this sentence doesn't mention school, this one confuses the meaning and seems to suggest that you eat your cold breakfast at home.
5. *We carry homemade breakfast to school* — This one is short and clear, though it doesn't mention that the breakfast is cold or made by the parents. If you wanted to wrap all these points up into one option, perhaps it would be something like:
6. *We bring a cold breakfast to school, made at home by our parents.*

Comment: before the  sentences I am asking about  I say "students have a luch in their classroom". That's the fist sentence. After saying that I wanted to  add "they have a cold breakfast made at home by their parents." Would it be correct?

Comment: Not "lunch" but "breakfast".

Comment: @AntoniaA If you're adding context to your original question, it's best to edit the question to include it there for future answerers. But I think you're asking: if the context talks about school, is option 4 (as numbered in my answer) clear? No, it still has trouble because to "have" a meal means to eat it. This doesn't usually use "a" ("They have *a* lunch,") but it could be taken that way, and it creates confusion about which meals they simply "have" in their possession and which ones they eat where.

Comment: To boil down my comments into something shorter and clearer: **I suggest using the verb *bring*.** (Assuming that you really are talking about how they *bring* food with them, not about them eating it.) Because "have" creates confusion about eating, and "carry" can be a little too specifically focused on the actual act of carrying.